# Sending Hex command to Printer using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, printing, hex

I'm trying to send an ESC sequence to a receipt printer to trigger the cash drawer to open. I'm a novice with Javascript so I just want to check I'm doing this right. Nothing is happening with the printer/cash drawer although I might be sending the wrong code sequence. 
I know the drawer does open, because I can use the printer test software to trigger it to open.

Here's the Javascript.

```
var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
var uniqueName = new Date();    
var windowName = 'CloseTillPrint' + uniqueName.getTime();
var PrintWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=300,top=100,width=200,height=900');      

PrintWindow.document.open('text/plain')

PrintWindow.document.write(0x1B); 
PrintWindow.document.write(0x70);
PrintWindow.document.write(0x30); 
PrintWindow.document.write(0x37); 
PrintWindow.document.write(0x79);
PrintWindow.document.close();
PrintWindow.focus();
PrintWindow.print();
PrintWindow.close();
```

If you can just confirm I haven't made any mistakes with the code above, I will assume I'm sending the wrong sequence of hex.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing numbers, not characters. Use this instead of your `write()` commands:

```
PrintWindow.document.write(String.fromCharCode(0x1B, 0x70, 0x30, 0x37, 0x79));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I don't think this is right. when I do as you suggested, I get characters printed out at the bottom of the receipt. Also when I googled your command "fromCharCode" I checked this page http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp and this confirms what I said.

Comment: Yes, you do get characters. More specifically, this: `p07y` However the first character, `0x1b`, is 27 in decimal, the ascii code for the Escape key. And while your code printed `27`, mine sent the actual Escape character. I had no idea whether my suggestion would work, but what you did was simply print numbers: `271124855121`.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation for the receipt printer? Maybe I can figure it out.

Comment: I'm getting the same characters you mentioned p07y, which actually appear at the bottom of the printout as text.. With regards to the manual, it's worse than useless. It's a Chinese import that a client has. I'm told it uses the command set for an Epson TM-T88. I'm confident that I now have the right codes, I just can't get them to the printer for some reason. This is the command I'm now using   PrintWindow.document.write(String.fromCharCode(0x1B, 0x70, 0x00, 0x19, 0xFA));

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you aren't really sending an escape sequence, you're sending _a printout_ of the escape sequence. The printer test software opens a direct line to the printer, then sends the escape sequence. But sending a print job to the printer, even if the print job contains an escape sequence, is an entirely different animal. The only way I can see to do this with JS is to have JavaScript request a resource from a server, then have that server run a command that opens the drawer.

Comment: Would there be a way to do this with PHP or HTML instead of JS. It doesnt  matter to me how it happens,as long as I can do it. BTW I managed to setup the printer properties to automatically open the cash drawer once a printout completes, but this doesnt help me if I want to JUST open the drawer, such as when they do cashing up.